# Children Component HTML not visible in VueJS

Tags: vuejs3

I have create Home Component which is imported into `App.vue`

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
  <home></home>
</template>

<script>
import home from "./components/home.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    home
  },
};
</script>
```

And header component is imported into `Home.vue`
**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <header></header>
</template>

<script>
import header from "./header.vue";
export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    header: header,
  },
};
</script>
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="new-component">
    <h1>A New Component</h1>
    <p>This is a text inside the NewComponent.</p>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'header',
}
</script>
```

When I check in browser I don't see HTML of header.vue
[image]

Comment: Where are you using the header component? I see that you are importing it but not using it

Comment: @jogarcia check now. sorry it was remove in formatter

Comment: What version of Vue are you using?

Comment: I am using vuejs3

Comment: jajjajaja, check out my answer bro, you'll find it amusing

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/ In this link you'll find info about that and other minor issues that you may have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multi word names. Your component is conflicting with **HTML**'s default `header` tag.

**VueHeader.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div class="new-component">
    <h1>A New Component</h1>
    <p>This is a text inside the NewComponent.</p>
  </div>
</template>

 <script>
export default {
  name: "vue-header",
};
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```html
<template>
  <vue-header></vue-header>
</template>

<script>
import VueHeader from "./VueHeader.vue";

export default {
  name: "home",
  components: {
    VueHeader,
  },
};
</script>
```

You can find more information about this and other minor issues in here [Vue style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/)

Comment: Haha.!! didn't know about it. but you solved it thanks